# In iOS, where are "Recently Deleted" folders located? (Jailbroken iDevice)

Tags: iphone, ios, itunes, ipad, jailbreak

I have a jailbroken iPad 4th gen with 15,000 pictures in Recently Deleted folder that iPad is unable to either recover or delete. Probably too many files for those functions to work.

I've installed NoRecentlyDelete tweak but it's a bit late.

So my question is, where is the folder(s) that holds those pictures so I can manually delete or recover them.

Note that I have access to raw file system on my iPad both via PC and iFile on iPad.

Cheers.

Comment: Polite Bump....

Answer (score 1):

The deleted pictures are going to be in `/var/mobile/Media/DCIM/` with the rest of your non-deleted pictures. When you delete a photo, iOS modifies a [SQLite database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQLite) located at `/var/mobile/Media/PhotoData/Photos.sqlite` to change which album the photo is stored in. Essentially, the photo's album is changed to 'Recently Deleted'. To get a list, you can run this SQLite query which returns a list of all deleted photos (including permanently deleted photos, which you will have to ignore).

```
SELECT
    (
        "/var/mobile/Media/"
        || ZGENERICASSET.ZDIRECTORY
        || "/"
        || ZGENERICASSET.ZFILENAME
    ) AS "FILENAME"
FROM
    ZGENERICASSET
WHERE
    ZGENERICASSET.ZTRASHEDSTATE = 1
;
```

[image]